# Prove that for $k$ a finite field every subset is closed (and open) in Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry, zariski-topology

The affine algebraic sets define a topology on the affine $n$-space, which is called the Zariski topology. I think that the algebraic sets are the closed sets in the Zariski topology, so I am not very sure of what I have to prove. Can someone please help me ? Also what if $k$ is not finite then what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, every point $(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ is closed since it is the zero set of the polynomials $x_i-a_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$. Now just use that finite unions of closed sets are closed.

This turns out to be wrong already for $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ if your field is infinite as the closed sets are exactly given by $V(0) = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ and the finite subsets of it (every non-zero polynomial in one variable has finitely many roots).

Comment: I didn't get the second part of your answer , the closed sets are given by $V(0)$ then how is it a contradiction.(I may sound stupid but I am very new to this).@TMO

Comment: Okay, let me expand that a bit. So we are considering the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ over an infinite field $k$. Since we are in dimension $1$, the closed (aka algebraic) sets are exactly the zero sets of polynomials $f \in k[x]$. Here two things can happen. If $f = 0$ is the zero polynomial, then we get $V(0) = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ since everything vanishes at $0$. If we take a non-zero polynomial $f \in k[x]$, it has finitely many roots which means that $V(f)$ is finite and we can obtain every finite set like that (see the first part of my original answer).

Comment: We just showed that the closed sets in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ are exactly the finite sets and the affine line itself. Thus, if we take any proper infinite subset $X \subset \mathbb{A}^1_k$, it cannot be closed. Hence this simple characterization does not work over infinite fields.

Comment: So in general the open subsets of a Zariski topology are in general the infinite set .So to take an example the set [0,1] is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ but is open in zariski topology $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ as there infinitely many points in the set .@TMO is this ok?

Comment: No, the open sets are exactly the complements of the sets above and $\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$ is not included there.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{-1,1,42\}\subset \Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb Q$, ...) is Zariski closed because it is the set of roots of $X^3-42X^2-X+42$. Similarly, every finite set of a field (i.e., of affine $1$-space) is closed. For a finite field, that's *all* subsets. And their complemets are the open sets ...